# How to declare parameter grid in XGBRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, xgbregressor

How do I implement the `param_grid` and get the best hyperparameters for xgb?

```
regressor = xgb.XGBRegressor()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

```
param_grid = {
    'max_depth' :[3,4,5],
    'learning_rate':[0.1, 0.01, 0.5],
    'gamma':[0,0.25,1],
    'reg_lambda':[0, 1.0, 10.0],
    'scale_pos_weight':[1,3,5]
}
```

```
optimal_params = GridSearchCV(estimator = xgb.XGBRegressor(subsample=0.9, colsample_bytree=0.5), param_grid = param_grid, verbose = 0,)
optimal_params.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose = False)
```

It takes forever to compile and shows this warning repeatedly:

```
[16:45:55] WARNING: /workspace/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:152: 
reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
```

Answer (score 1):

This all looks correct.

You have `3*3*3*3*3=243` hyperparameter combinations to check, so it probably will take some time (you can estimate this by fitting one of them first and multiplying by 243, though of course some hyperparameters will affect the training time).  You might consider `RandomizedSearchCV` instead if it is prohibitively long.

The warning is just a warning, not an error; you can silence it as it suggests, by setting your objective to `reg:squarederror` (or upgrading your xgboost package, since that is the current default).